# Evaluate the indefinite integral $\int\frac{dx}{(1+e^x)^2}$

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

> Evaluate the indefinite integral $$\int\frac{dx}{(1+e^x)^2}$$

There is some clever trick to solve this, I think.

I'm really hesitant to ask a homework question without submitting an attempted solution, but this question is not very conducive towards partial solutions.

Comment: There was a little mistake in the answer. I'm correcting it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are given $$I = \int {\frac{{dx}}{{{{\left( {{e^x} + 1} \right)}^2}}}} $$

Let $e^x+1=u$. Then, what does you integral become?

**SPOILER** You should get

> $I =  \displaystyle \int {\frac{{du}}{{{u^2}\left( {u - 1} \right)}}}$

Then use partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: Your original mistake was in distributing under a square, right?

Comment: No, I mixed up denominators.

Comment: Oh darn. I wanted to see your original solution so that I could figure it out, so I tried to build it by memory but failed when I couldn't distribute under a square.

Comment: Also, I like this solution better. It's less deus ex machina. I just didn't think ahead. Thanks!

Comment: @user72273 See the edit history. One denominator was $(e^x+e^{2x})^2$ and the other was $(e^x+1)^2$.

Comment: I've even seen this trick before. Embarrassing...

Answer (score 2):

If you make the change of variables $u=e^x$ then you get

$$\int\frac{1}{(1+e^x)^2}=\int\frac{1}{u(1+u)^2}=-\int\frac{1}{u+1}-\int\frac{1}{(u+1)^2}+\int\frac{1}{u}=$$
$$=\frac{(1+u)(\log{u}-\log{(u+1))+1}}{u+1}$$

Now undo the change of variables, operate an you will get

$\int\frac{1}{(1+e^x)^2}=x+\frac{1}{e^x+1}+\log{(e^x+1)}+K$

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle \int\frac{1}{(1+e^x)^2}dx = \int\frac{e^{-x}.e^{-x}}{(e^{-x}+1)^2}dx$

Let $e^{-x}+1=t\Leftrightarrow -e^{-x}dx = dt\Leftrightarrow e^{-x}dx = -dt$

So $\displaystyle -\int \frac{(t-1)}{t^2}dt = \int \frac{1-t}{t^2}dt=\int t^{-2}dt-\int \frac{1}{t}dt$

$\displaystyle = -\frac{1}{t}-\ln \mid t \mid +C$

$\displaystyle = -\frac{1}{e^{-x}+1}-\ln \mid e^{-x}+1 \mid+C$